# Is there a (static) JavaScript function call trace tool?

Tags: javascript, static-code-analysis

My JS code is getting bigger and bigger and also older. This means that, while working on other projects, I tend to forget all the sequences in which I call my functions. I would like to know if there's a tool which can parse my .js file and produce a (simple) document in which each function has listed all the other function it call. This is just a static source code analysis; I don't need it to do anything at run time.

Overly simplified example:

```
function firstFunction(){
    ...
    secondFunction();
    thirdFunction(); 
}

function secondFunction(){
    ...
    thirdFunction(); 
}

function thirdFunction(){
    ...
    secondFunction();
    firstFunction(); 
}
```

The resulted (text) document would simply list the function calls (I don't care about format):

```
firstFunction: secondFunction, thirdFunction 
secondFunction: thirdFunction
thirdFunction: secondFunction, firstFunction
```

**EDIT:** please note that I would like not to change my code; I have tens of functions with some of them calling more than 10-15 other functions; printing messages before or after each function call would require to much time, both for writing and running each scenario.

**EDIT no.2:** I could do this with any basic text editor by selecting each function name and searching for instances of that name in the file; this method would require much more time and brain cells than I can afford right now; an automated tool would have been perfect.

Comment: there is something called console.log where you log the strings in javascript which logs your strings to browser console. Note IE7 and below do not have console object and may throw error. you need to take care of that too.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal console.log would require that I modify my existing code. I would like it to work "offline", whereas console.log would require me to go trough every possible scenario.

Comment: @LightStyle I don't need to log anything at run time. What I need is something which resemble more to a documentation. I don't care if the code is correct or not, or whether it breaks in the browser. I need a document which I can read over and over again and even print.

Answer (score 0):

console.trace() works very well on Google Chrome. In addition console.log() could be handy, when console.log() is called, the stacktrace is also displayed.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. Please re-read the question.

Comment: I need something static, to just parse the code. It takes me to much time to log the function call as I have tens of functions that are reference from one-another. I'm trying not to _touch_ the code.